# How to setup OAuth2-compliant Identity Provider with Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, okta

I want to set up an OAuth2-compliant Identity Provider with Azure but am unable to find any useful links, earlier i was able to set up the same for Okta using the below steps

To configure Okta as Identity Provider:

1. Sign up for a free developer account at developer.okta.com
2. In Okta Developer Console, create an application: Applications ->Add Application ->Service ->Done.
3. Add default scope: API -> Authorization Servers ->Select “default” ->Scopes -> Add Scope. Enter name, and description, and check “Default scope”.

is there any way in azure so i can achieve the same.

in other words, how to setup OpenID connect with Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same can be achieved in Azure with Azure Active Directory. You would have to [register an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) and configure the same from the Portal UI for your application like [exposing app specific scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis).

The linked how-to docs from the official docs cover various other aspects like signing in users, app roles, tokens, claims, etc.